# Binding errors with list

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I generated a form:

```
<form:form action="${contextPath}/draw/constraints.do" method="post" modelAttribute="order"> <c:forEach items="${order.myDrawsAsArray}" var="draw" varStatus="status">
<label class="radio-inline"><form:radiobutton path="myDrawsAsArray[${status.index}].readable" value="true" /> yes</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><form:radiobutton path="myDrawsAsArray[${status.index}].readable" value="false" /> no</label>
</c:forEach></form:form>
```

When I submit it to update my entities, I got the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'myDrawsAsArray[0]' of bean class [com.entity.Order3d]: Getter
>   for property 'myDrawsAsArray' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'myDrawsAsArray[0]' of bean class [com.entity.Order3d]: Getter
>   for property 'myDrawsAsArray' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.entity.Order3d.getMyDrawsAsArray(Order3d.java:121)

My controller is like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/draw")
public class PrintingController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/constraints")
    public String constraints(
                @ModelAttribute Order3d order,
                @RequestParam("order") int id,
                @RequestParam(value="save", required=false) String save,
                Model m) {
        Session s=HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        if(save!=null) {
            System.out.println(order.getMyDraws());
            for(DrawFile df : order.getMyDraws())
                s.saveOrUpdate(df);
        }
        Order3d o=(Order3d)s.createCriteria(Order3d.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
        m.addAttribute("order", o);
        s.close();
        return "3dconstraints";
    }
}
```

I also post my entities if you need them:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="order3d")
public class Order3d implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2241346447352903470L;
    public enum State {DEMAND, ESTIMATED, PAYED, PENDING, PRODUCED, SENT, DELIVERED};
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order3d", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<DrawFile> myDraws;
public Set<DrawFile> getMyDraws() {
    return myDraws;
}
public List<DrawFile> getMyDrawsAsList() {
    return new ArrayList<DrawFile>(myDraws);
}
public Object[] getMyDrawsAsArray() {
    return myDraws.toArray(); //line 121
}
    //other getters & setters
    public Order3d() {}
}
@Entity
@Table (name="draw", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="hashname"))
public class DrawFile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9024754876558087847L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="hashname", columnDefinition="CHAR(64)")
    private String hashname;
    @Column (name="filename")
    private String filename="";
    @Column (name="readable", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
    private Boolean readable;
    //getters & setters
    public DrawFile() {}
}
```

I searched on the web but I didn't find a solution. Any idea?

Comment: u cannot read a Set using [index]

Comment: I now return a List with `public List<DrawFile> getMyDrawsAsList();` but I got a new Exception: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'myDrawsAsList[0]' of bean class [com.entity.Order3d]: Getter for property 'myDrawsAsList' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
`

Comment: I just did but I got errors (I updated my 1st post: getters, JSP and exception)

Answer (score 0):

How about try adding getter/setter to the fields in both Order3d and DrawFile classes?

The getters and setters must match field name, if the field is

```
List<DrawFile> myDraws;
```

then the getter/setter must be: (it cannot be getMyDrawsAsList())

```
public List<DrawFile> getMyDraws() {
    return myDraws;
}


public void setMyDraws(List<DrawFile> myDraws) {
    this.myDraws = myDraws;
}
```

Comment: I added getters related to my Set, changed my JSP to get an Array but I throw a new exception

Comment: Define getter and setter on the boolean flag please